# bit wise counter on a single byte javascript

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit

I want to use the bits valued at 2^4-2^8 in a Typed 16Uint array item to use as a binary counter to 16.

```
0000111100000000 ->15
0000111000000000 ->14
0000110100000000 ->13
...
0000000000000000 ->0
```

is there a simple bit wise operation that would count in binary? 
my current strategy is to extract the bits as number add one - do some error checking, then set the bits in the original with a&0 and replace that part with a |or mask?

```
cellBinary = iterate(cellBinary, 16, 4);
function iterate(cellBinary, start, length)
    {
    let number = extractBits(cellBinary, start, length);
    if(number < 15)
        {
        number++;
    }
    what = eraseIterator(what);
    what = what|number;
    return what;
}
function extractBits(what, start, length)
    {
    return ((1 << start ) -1) & (what >> (length - 1));
}
function eraseIterator(what)
    {
    what&16^1; //also iffy if this will work as intended.
    what&32^1; //this is supposed to set 16-128 to 0.
    what&64^1;
    what&128^1; 
    return what;
}
```

is there a better way to accomplish this?
note: code is an example, I'm looking for a strategy, not a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the right amount directly: 256, 100000000 in binary.

For example,

```
000000000000 + 100000000 ->
000100000000
001000000000
001100000000
...
111100000000
```

> the bits valued at 2^4-2^8

That would mean this sequence:

```
00000000
00010000
00100000
00110000
...
11110000
```

Or in other words, add 16.

Comment: @altruios much easier: `if (value < 0xF0) value += 16`

Comment: Or 0xF00 and 256 for the version with 8 padding bits, it's not really clear to me which one of them you meant

Comment: so:

that makes a lot of sense.
i'm not used to working with bitwise stuff, that seems like a really good way to think about it.